# Output of Android ADB devices command has changed

Tags: android, adb

I just started receiving a different output from the ADB devices command. This is what I am seeing with a USB-connected and a Wireless-connected Android devices:

```
List of devices attached
ZF65246GPF             device product:ocean model:moto_g_7__power device:ocean transport_id:2
adb-RF8M70MPJ8K-EonbQL._adb-tls-connect._tcp device product:a10ub model:SM_A105M device:a10 transport_id:3
```

Normally the IPAddress:Port would be displayed in place of the "adb-RF8M70MPJ8K-EonbQL._adb-tls-connect._tcp" for the wireless device. Something has changed.

```
ADB version: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 34.0.5-10900879
Android version: 13  Kernel: 5.10.136 Sep 18 2023
```

Has anybody else seen this? Workaround?

Comment: Hopefully you don't try to parse the output of `adb devices` by an application. There are better ways which directly communicate with the adb server.

Comment: Actually I do use the output of the command. I wasn't aware of communicating directly with the ADB server. More info is always welcome. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: The adb server instance really thing in background on the PC communicates with the adb command-line process over TCP with a defined protocol. So you don't need the adb command-line client. For cer gain languages there are libraries available which directly communicate with adb server. I don't know what programming language you use, but just check f there is such a library available.

Comment: C# is the primary language I use